# Variance of noisy data makes unexpected jump

Tags: python, variance

I observer a somewhat surprising result.

I have a probability distribution of some object in space. I would like to find the variance of that probability distribution. However, there is a catch. The probability distribution I get is corrupted by small amounts of white noise. My naive approach to fix it is as follows:

1. Subtract minimum from the corrupted function
2. Normalize it
3. Calculate the variance

Somewhat surprisingly, for very mild amounts of noise my estimator can be wrong by a factor of 10 !!!

Why so much, and is there a better way to estimate variance in my case? For my actual application I do not know the variance of the noise.

```
def var(x, y):
    p = y - np.min(y)
    p /= np.sum(y)
    mu = p.dot(x)
    return p.dot((x - mu)**2)


gau = lambda mu, s2: np.exp(-(mu**2)/s2/2) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * s2)

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
y = gau(x - 50, 50)
ynoisy = y + np.random.normal(0, 0.001, 100)

print("Original variance", var(x, y))
print("Noisy variance", var(x, ynoisy))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, ynoisy)
plt.show()
```

> Original variance 49.99999993042545
>
> Noisy variance 412.4350189819331

[image: py]

Comment: I don't know about the factor of 10, but what's seems VERY disturbing to me is the fact that (a) your noise distribution is not guaranteed to be normalized to 1 and, more importantly, (b) may assume negative values, which invalidates the approach as a whole. Try multiplicative noise and renormalization instead

Comment: @AndreasSteimer (a) I do not understand what you mean by normalizing the noise (b) I don't get to choose. The problem I have to solve is with additive noise.

Comment: (a) what I mean is that by adding noise to the pdf (NOT the underlying random variables) you cannot guarantee the resulting pdf to remain normalized to 1 (as it is necessary for any pdf) (b) Then something is at odds here, since your noisy pdf obtains negative values, which doesn't make sense. Are you sure that adding noise to the pdf (rather than the random variables) is a must for the task at hand?

Comment: @AndreasSteimer You are indeed correct. The main variable I am plotting is not really a probability distribution. It is some mono-modal signal. I am trying to figure out where its center is and how far it spreads. I don't even care that the spread is measured by variance - I would accept any stable measure that is larger for more dispersed modes and smaller for more compact. Converting the signal to a pdf is an auxiliary step to achieve this, I would gladly skip it if there was a more robust way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now it is much clearer what you want to achieve and also why the proposed approach doesn't work. This is because the minimum of the noisy function can occur anywhere, most likely in the outer flanks where the function is close to zero. So imagine a large negative minimum to occur close to the ends of the plot. This means that you will create a huge offset in order to produce a pdf for which to compute the variance. Unlike a gaussian, this offset (together with the remoteness of the minimum from the maximum) then translates into a large probability mass in those outer regions, which will heavily distort your variance measure.

So how can that be remedied? I suggest you to try what is called Laplaces method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method), which boils down to fitting a second-order polynomial to the logarithm of your noisy function (or equivalently to the local approximation of the function by a gaussian).

For this approach to work however you need to make sure that (a) the function can reasonably be approximated locally by a gaussian 
and 
(b) that this local region consists of positive values only

Comment: It looks promising. I'll give it a try and get back to you. Hopefully it is more stable than my pdf stuff

Comment: It should work under the premises I gave in the answer. Good luck

Comment: Just to let you know. I have tried the method you propose. Since my data can be negative due to noise, I have to subtract the minimum and a small fixed number to ensure that the data is positive. When I afterwards try to fit a polynomial to the logarithm, I recover the mean correctly, but the variance is wrong. Further, the variance does not seem to change much when I vary the variance of the source data. Unfortunately, this method also does not work for my problem. It seems I need a method that can account for additive noise with nonzero mean.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. But what is the reason for the method not to work? For example, do you have a plot displaying the quality of the fit in the log-domain? Sometimes some nitty-gritty preprocessing steps need to be do done before fitting can be applied

Comment: If you like you can also provide me with some of your data and I will try my best to fit it

Comment: Thanks so much for your supprt. The major problem is that when we fit quadratic to the logarithm, we are concerned with relative error. So if some value in the tail of a gaussian is supposed to be $10^{-18}$ and it is $0.01$, that would be considered a way more dramatic error than those in the center. Thus, the behaviour of the fit is dictated by the points most far away from the mean, which is undesirable. If you wish, you can try. Sample a gaussian function over 100 points, add some noise, fit a gaussian to the result, and see if the predicted variance grows when true variance grows.

Comment: I think I have converged to the understanding that my question is ill-posed beyond help. As always, the actual problem is more complicated. I hoped to attack it with gaussians, but I think it is wrong approach. My true problem is to estimate the "spread" of an arbitrary non-negative function over fixed interval. I thought that variance was a good measure of the spread, but it seems very hard to estimate robustly. I will ask the question again on the forum in its most general form. Perhaps it opens doors to other approaches

Comment: That's what I have suspected and it is the reason for why I've used the term "locally" in my answer above (maybe I should have been more explicit about that). The point of Laplaces method is that a LOCAL approximation is performed to the function around the maximum,which is reflected by a Taylor approximation. This is all the more important if you are dealing with data in the log-domain.Thus,try to only use data from a "reasonably tight" interval around the max, NOT the whole data from the tails. Play with the interval length & see how the fit is deteriorating if the interval becomes too large

Comment: Don't throw the towel yet. If your displayed example is representative of the task it should be solvable. I'll also try to solve it based on your 100 points procedure

Comment: That's the point. It is not representative at all. I have tried the method on gaussians because I wanted to check how it works on easy examples. In reality I can have more or less any function as input. I know for sure that the function has additive noise. I also know that it has reasonably good SNR. I can make sure it is always positive, but the added noise is going to have a positive mean. Gaussian is not a good fit for my function in 99.999% cases. My goal is to find the spread of an arbitrary function over a fixed interval

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107590/discussion-between-andreas-steimer-and-aleksejs-fomins).